# is it wrong to allow a secret key for dynamodb read only user to be made public?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

So I have a dynamodb table and I have used the iam console to create a user in a group that has read only access to the table.

What are the issues with having this users private key in client side javascript so I can sign GET requests to the table and use ajax to pull directly from the table? I mean if all the information in the table is publicly available it doesn't matter if read only access key is known does it?

I know I can set up a token vending machine, but I was wondering for read only access to a table whose entire contents are publicly available could I bypass the TVM and not care about exposing a private key?

Answer (score 1):

This actually seems like a really bad idea.  You should implement a webservice in between your javascript and Dynamo.  This will offer a few benefits:

- You will hide the DB credentials from the end user
- You would have control over the CORS policy for the server to actually allow a cross domain request
- You would have control over verifying that the request is coming from a valid user such that you should pass the request along to Dynamo
- You can format the response to the client in a way that is most convenient for consumption in javascript
- You can introduce response caching if appropriate to further reduce reads on Dynamo
- You can place database interaction logic on the server where it is easier to maintain/improve and rollout changes to clients.

Answer (score 0):

You could be a victim of a DoS attack that would be a pain to defend from.

Suppose the attacker gets your key and starts to make tons and tons of requests: you could have all your read units consumed, which would cause problems for other clients. If you cancel that token, then all the other, legitimate users, would also have problems. Finally, if you have auto-scaling, you could end up with a huge bill.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Would such a scenario also be possible using a temporary (i.e tvm generated) key which have a 12 hour default life span?